# Google Maps API: Referrer not allowed

Tags: api, maps

So I've created a website that is being hosted on Github Pages. The problem I have is that the Google Maps API gives me the 'referrer not allowed' error when I open up the console. I've looked on here for answers and can only find ones that mention changing the syntax of the website that you list as a referrer. But I've tried this - added * to the beginning and end and every combination, removed 'www.', removed 'https://' - everything.

I'm still getting the same error, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the URL that is loading the maps to the allowed referrer. Go to your referrer setting of API in cloud console. Add it there.
I got the same error.